# Filter the use of validator for certain values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydantic

Is it possible to just execute a validator for a certain value?
Let's say I have the following case, where I have a class with two boolean fields and I use a validator to make sure that `field1` can't be True when `field2` is set to True:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator


class MyClass(BaseModel):
    field1: bool
    field2: bool

    @validator('field2')
    def both_fields_are_true(cls, v, values):
        field1 = values.get('field1')
        if field1 and field2:
            raise ValueError
        return v

myClass = MyClass(field1=True, field2=False)
```

The instance `myClass` will run the validator, but it is not needed as the second field is set to False, and then, the validation does not make sense anymore.

How can I avoid my class from executing the validation in such a case like that? I know the result will be the same anyway, but it is good to avoid executing things when they're not needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [@root_validator](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/#root-validators), which is performed on the entire model's data:

```
class MyClass(BaseModel):
    field1: bool
    field2: bool

    @root_validator
    def both_fields_are_true(cls,  values):
        field1, field2 = values.get('field1'), values.get('field2')
        if field1 and field2:
            raise ValueError('Both fields are true')
        return values


myClass = MyClass(field1=True, field2=False)
```

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but this looks just like another way of performing the same validation, but it is not answering my question. What I want is to avoid doing the validation if `field2 = False`, as in that case, I don't have to take care of `field1` value. Kind of a previous validation, where depending of the value of `field2`, `both_fields_are_true` would wether be executed or not.

Comment: then you can just on the first line do: if not field2: return values

Comment: Yes, this should be enough, in case that Pydantic doesn't include any other solution. Thanks!